# How to create a folder and write a file into that folder in isolated storage explorer in windows phone 7 application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I can create the folder in Isolated Storage Explorer, but not write the file into that folder. When I use the code like:

```
IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
store.CreateDirectory("JSON");
using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("JSON\\dd.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store))
{
    using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
    {
        isoFileWriter.WriteLine(jsonFile);
    }
}
```

only create the folder, but there is no file in that folder. Please give sample code for creating  folder in Isolated Storage Explorer and writing a file into that folder.  It is a WP7 application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried by using the isoFileStream.Write directly instead of using the StreamWriter object isoFileWriter.

Please use following code and try

```
IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
store.CreateDirectory("JSON");
using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("JSON\\dd.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store))
{
   isoFileStream.Write(jsonFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    // Obtain the virtual store for the application.
    IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    iso.CreateDirectory("Database");
    // Create stream for the file in the installation folder.
    using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("test.sdf", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
    {
        // Create stream for the new file in the isolated storage
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile("Database\\test.sdf"))
        {
            // Initialize the buffer
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            // Copy the file from installation folder to isolated storage.
            while((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is similar to mine which I use to copy database from application instalation folder to specific folder under isolated storage. Hope it will help you with some inspiration :)